# Reload the Same Page with Tampermonkey Should Re-run Script

Tags: javascript, html, greasemonkey, tampermonkey

I have a page with a URL like:

https://some-github-like-page.com/pulls?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Apr+label%3AOptimization+sort%3Acomments-asc

This page runs my tampermonkey script just fine.

Sidebar: With my tampermonkey script, I run some AJAX queries to enhance the page's table of open github pull requests by showing code reviewers that have responded, approved, commented, done nothing or ... In addition, the number of files changed in the pull request is displayed. This script is used during code review time to get a handle on open pull requests and the code reviews needed.

In the page, there exists some HTML code to sort the pull request ... some repeated items have HTML code like this:

```
<a href="/pulls?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Apr+label%3AOptimization" class="select-menu-item" aria-checked="true" role="menuitemradio">
          <svg class="octicon octicon-check select-menu-item-icon" viewBox="0 0 12 16" version="1.1" width="12" height="16" aria-hidden="true"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M12 5l-8 8-4-4 1.5-1.5L4 10l6.5-6.5L12 5z"></path></svg>
          <div class="select-menu-item-text">Least commented</div>
</a>
<a href="/pulls?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Apr+label%3AOptimization+sort%3Aupdated-desc" class="select-menu-item" aria-checked="false" role="menuitemradio">
          <svg class="octicon octicon-check select-menu-item-icon" viewBox="0 0 12 16" version="1.1" width="12" height="16" aria-hidden="true"><path fill-rule="evenodd" d="M12 5l-8 8-4-4 1.5-1.5L4 10l6.5-6.5L12 5z"></path></svg>
          <div class="select-menu-item-text">Recently updated</div>
</a>
...
```

The above code should sort items on the page from the server side.

The issue is that when I click on this anchor (seen above). The script does not run again ... even as the omnibar shows the new URL.

I tried a few versions of @run-at but did not get see the script run again.

Here is psuedo-copy of the header:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         Turbo Code Review Requests Preview
// @namespace    http://some-company.com/tampermonkey
// @version      0.3
// @updateURL    https://internal-company.com/nursery/tools/raw/master/UserScripts/TurboCodeReview/Turbo%20Code%20Review%20Requests.user.js
// @description  Give an enhanced view of Pull Requests Status
// @author       SWarren and ...
// @include      https://some-github-like-page.com/pulls?*
// @grant GM_xmlhttpRequest
// @run-at document-start
```

How can tampermonkey be forced to run when this sort of 'new page' loads? I can modify the tampermonkey headers or inject something into the 'sort' elements above?

Comment: See [Fire Greasemonkey script on AJAX request](//stackoverflow.com/a/8283815)

Comment: @wOxxOm Umm ... The issue seems to not be an AJAX request as clicking on the anchors causes this issue. I guess the issue may be related to the fact that the clicked-to page is thought to be same as the page displayed prior. If I refresh the clicked-to (or second) page, the script runs again.

Comment: The page makes its own AJAX requests and updates the URL using History API so this is exactly the solution you're looking for.